# Connect a computer through the internet with a local ad-hoc network

Tags: lan, ad-hoc-network

We have a local network (several laptops) using an ad-hoc network, where one laptop is the host for a game.

How can I connect a distant laptop through the internet to that ad-hoc network and be able to play games with them for example?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to install `openvpn` on the distant laptop and on the pc that is hosting the adhoc. Run the distant laptop as a client and the local as a vpn server.

That way there will be a tunnel between those two laptops and the distant one will be seen as a local laptop with a virtual IP assigned.